# Matlab multiple indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a matrix like this one:

```
a= [ 61 65 63 ; ...
     21 21 24 ; ...
     34 2 51 ]
b= [ -1 0 8; ...
      -2 0 6; ...
      -4 0 2]
c=cat(3,a,b)
```

What I want to do is to find by rows of the first dimension on c the highest value, and then based on these values to get the values at the row and column but in the third dimension of c.

In my example, I am trying the following:

```
 [maxV,colIndx] =max(c,[],2)

 m=maxV(:,:,1)
 f=c(:,colIndx(:,1,1),2)
```

The vector m return half of my answer, ie

```
m =

    65
    24
    51
```

now, I want f to be like

```
f =

    0
    6
    2
```

However, my code doesn't return what I want. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have read over [find](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and try to implement that. If it doesn't work edit your question with what you tried.

Comment: I read the instruction for find but I don't think it helps in my problem as I already know the index, I just want to get the specific elements from the matrix. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try using linear indexing via the `sub2ind` function:

```
linIndx = sub2ind(size(c), (1:(size(c,1)))', colIndx(:,:,1), ones(size(c,1),1)*2);
f = c(linIndx)
```